# Mysql 5.7 Innodb Delete query very slow randomly

Tags: php, mysql, query-performance

I have table with 5 simple fields. Total rows in table is cca 250.

When I use PHPmyAdmin with one DELETE query it is processed in 0.05 sec. (always).

Problem is that my PHP application (PDO connection) processing same query between other queries and this query is extremely slow (cca 10 sec.). And another SELECT query on table with 5 rows too (cca 1 sec.). It happened only sometimes!
Other queries (cca 100) are always OK with normal time response.

What problem should be or how to find what is the problem?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `list_ip` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`address` CHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`description` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `address` (`address`),
INDEX `type` (`type`),
INDEX `datetime` (`datetime`) ) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Query:

```
DELETE FROM list_ip WHERE address='1.2.3.4' AND type='INT' AND datetime<='2017-12-06 08:04:30';
```

As I said before table has only 250 rows. Size of table is 96Kib.
I tested also with empty table and its slow too.

Comment: What does cca mean?

Comment: @bassxzero Was about to ask the same thing. I'm assuming approximately?

Comment: cca = *circa* or *approximately.*

Comment: @O.Jones is that common knowledge? Am I retarded?

Comment: @bassxzero Yes. And yes.

Comment: @omerowitz feelsbadman.jpg

Comment: Without supplying tables structure and query example it is really difficult to investigate roots of your problem. It could be anything - intern or extern reason - e.g. DNS issue, network/connection random latency, concurrent queries, table locking etc..

Comment: @bassxzero It's a tough crowd here, isn't it?

Comment: Please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please pay special attention to the section on query performance. Please [edit] your question to offer more information. Please tell us how busy your php application is when you have this problem. Your problem could be due to many things, and more information will let SO contributors help you rule out the simple stuff.

Comment: (cca was a new one on me, too)

Comment: Do you have transactions?  Is it InnoDB?  How are you measuring the PDO time?

Comment: @rick-james No transactions, Yes, InnoDB, Time is differences between other queries when I log all queries.

Comment: `ERROR 1061 (42000): Duplicate key name 'type'`

Comment: Don't use `CHAR` for variable length strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some network problem. I uninstalled docker app with some network peripherals and looks much beter.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your query in EXPLAIN  and  see if it's running a sequential select, not using indexes.   EXPLAIN would be my first stop in determining if I have a data model problem (bad / missing indexes would be one model issue).

About EXPLAIN:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Another tool I'd recommend is running  'mytop' and looking at the server activity/load during those times when it's bogging down.    http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/

Comment: May I add a suggestion to turn the slow query logging on too

Comment: Not sure that will be a huge benefit here, since they seem to know which is running slowly, but I agree that it's generally a good practice, especially when trying to sort out a lag/bog.

Comment: Just to make sure the problem resides with the db, not caused by the app or network....

Comment: I am building all tables with required indexes and auto_increment. 2 problematic tables are not joining, just simple queries. EXPLAIN said nothing extra. By me its something with Mysql server, communication or similar problem. :-(